# Phone calls following Poisson process

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-process

We assume that phone calls arrive according to a Poisson process with rate 2. If I know that up to time t = 1 there is one call only, how likely is it that it arrived after t = 0.75? If I know that up to time t = 1 two calls arrived, how likely is it that the second arrived after t = 0.75?

So for the first problem I set that
$P(S_1>0.75/X(1)=1)$, with $S_1$, the time it takes for the first event to occur, and $X(1)$, the number of events that occurred up to time 1. But then I don't quite see how to handle it.

Comment: The event $[0.75<X_1\leqslant1]$ does not forbid more than one call before time $1$.

Comment: If you correct this, you should reach the conclusion that, conditionally on the event that there is exactly one arrival before time 1, this arrival is uniformly distributed on (0,1) (an observation that yields readily the first answer, the second case being similar).

Comment: You're right. My first event doesn't make sense, it should have written $P(S_1 > 0.75 / X(1) =1)$
I know about the uniform distribution but then I must say I'm quite lost with how to handle my formula

Comment: You seem to have changed notations between your question and your last comment. Please define $X_n$, $X(n)$ and $S_n$.

Comment: Edited. $X_n$ was a mistake of mine.

Comment: OK, so now you might want to use the fact that $[X(1)=1]=[S_1\leqslant 1<S_2]$ hence you are after $$\frac{P(0.75<S_1\leqslant 1<S_2)}{P(S_1\leqslant 1<S_2)}$$ Can you compute this ratio?

Comment: So here you're using the formula to compute $P(S_1 > 0.75 / S_1 ⩽ 1 < S_2)$ if I follow you. But I don't see how you compute you numerator.

Comment: I did not (compute the numerator) but I am saying that this is what one should do and that this computation is direct. How would you do it?

Comment: For me I understand that $P(S_1 ⩽ 1 < S_2) = 1$ because it is given. I don't see how to handle the bigger inequality.

Comment: No, $P(S_1\leqslant1<S_2)$ is not $1$, already $P(S_1>1)=e^{-2}\ne0$.

Comment: So it means I really doesn't see what that double inequality means in computational terms.

Comment: I do not know what (to) "mean in computational terms" means. To compute $P(S_1\leqslant1<S_2)$, one needs the joint distribution of $(S_1,S_2)$. What is it, already?

Comment: Do you mean $P(S_1 ⩽ 1, S_2 > 1) = P(S_1 ⩽ 1)*P(S_2 > 1)$ ?

Comment: This would require that $(S_1,S_2)$ is independent. Is it? (No.) Please think more seriously about the problem and about the **precise indications** I gave, believe it or not, they were not written randomly.

Comment: Thanks for your help. We will try other exercises and come back to this one with a fresh mind, maybe we will see something we actually don't